# Finding Rserve Rconfig file on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu, configuration-files, rserve

The docs say it should be located in `/etc/Rserv.conf` which it is not in my case using Ubuntu 13.10.

When I run `sudo find / 'Rserv.conf'` or `sudo find / '*Rserv.conf'` it returns no such file.

However Rserve is working fine.

I'm pretty new to linux so maybe I am messing something up here.

Where and how can I locate this config file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no config file installed by default, the function `run.RServe` just looks for a file at the location `/etc/Rserv.conf`.

This is from the [RForge RServe page](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/doc.html):

**Configuration**

> Rserve is configured by the configuration file /etc/Rserv.conf (can be
>   changed at compile time by specifying -DCONFIG_FILE=..). Additional
>   configuration files can be added by the --RS-conf command line
>   argument. The possible configuration entries are as follows (all
>   entries are optional; default values are in angled brackets):

```
workdir <path> [/tmp/Rserv]
pwdfile <file> [none=disabled]
remote enable|disable [disable]
auth required|disable [disable]
plaintext enable|disable [disable]
fileio enable|disable [enable]
interactive yes|no [yes] (since 0.6-2)

(since version 0.1-9):
socket <socket> [none=disabled]
port <port> [6311]
maxinbuf <size in kb> [262144]

(since version 0.3):
maxsendbuf <size in kb> [0=unlimited]
uid <uid> [none]
gid <gid> [none]
su now|server|client [none] (since 0.6-1)

(since version 0.3-16):
source <file>
eval <expressions>

(since version 0.5 and unix only):
chroot <directory> [none]
sockmod <mode> [0=default]
umask <mask> [0]

(since version 0.5-3):
encoding native|utf8|latin1 [native]
(since version 0.6-2):
```

> Since 0.5 the following configuration options can use either
>   hexadecimal (0x..), octal (0..) or decimal values: port, uid, gid,
>   umask and sockmode. All other options and command-line options always
>   assume decimal notation.